# Upgraded DRC Simulator, and now roslaunch UI fails to load for atlas

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Upgraded DRC Simulator, and now roslaunch UI fails to load for atlas.
Anyone know the cause? - Thanks, Aaron

gazebo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/drcsim-2.1/plugins/libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6gazebo9transport9PublisherC1ERKSsS3_j
Warning [gazebo_main.cc:62] escalating to SIGKILL on client
[gazebo-2] process has finished cleanly

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1961/upgraded-drc-simulator,-and-now-roslaunch-ui-fails-to-load-for-atlas./) by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/272/unknown_entity1/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sounds like a version mismatch between drcsim and gazebo.  In particular, you probably have drcsim 2.1.x + gazebo 1.5.x, which is an unsupported configuration.

Try an update and explicit install of both, which should get you to drcsim 2.2.x + gazebo 1.5.x:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install drcsim gazebo
```

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/272/unknown_entity1/) on 2013-03-20**:
Didn't work, and I received the following error: gazebo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/drcsim-2.1/plugins/libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6gazebo9transport9PublisherC1ERKSsS3_j

Error [Connection.cc:477] Connection[0] Closed during Read
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::system::system_error'
what():  Connection reset by peer
[gazebo-2] process has finished cleanly

**Comment by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/272/unknown_entity1/) on 2013-03-20**:
The following was the output from the sudo apt-get..  sudo apt-get install drcsim gazebo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
drcsim is already the newest version.
gazebo is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.

**Comment by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/272/unknown_entity1/) on 2013-03-20**:
I wonder if the installer is failing to install because I don't have an AMD64 for the 64-bit package for the Boston Dynamics addition?

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-03-21**:
Oh, that would definitely do it.  In that case, `apt-get` will refuse to upgrade your drcsim to 2.2.0, leaving you with an incompatible version combination.  You should either move to a 64-bit machine or build drcsim 2.2.0 from source.

**Comment by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) on 2013-03-21**:
Having exactly the same problem as this poster - I can't update from drcsim-2.1, and now I have gazebo-1.5 with it and nothing's working.  We run an intel chip, that doesn't seem to be the problem.  What would cause the apt-get update to not detect that 2.2 is available?  My keys seem correct, nothing else has change with my installer lists.

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-03-21**:
@DRC_Justin: are you running on 32-bit or 64-bit?  Try `uname -m`.  If it returns `x86_64` or `amd64`, you're on 64-bit.  If it returns something else (probably `x86`), you're on 32-bit.

**Comment by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) on 2013-03-21**:
@gerkey: We are running 32 bit.  It returned i686.  What should we be running?